# When does Android set a view's pivotX and pivotY values?

Tags: android, view, pivot

I have an ImageView which is sometimes, but not always, being positioned incorrectly. It appears that sometimes it gets displayed before its pivotX and pivotY values are set. So they are both zero and the ImageView appears in the upper left hand corner of its space. And once drawn, both pivotX and pivotY never get set for that View and it remains out of place.  I can "fix" it by explicitly setting pivotX and pivotY in the XML. But that is a hack. Better to determine root cause and find out when pivotX and pivotY *should* be set to understand why they aren't. Clearly it is a multi-threading issue and something is (somehow) drawing the image before it is properly initialized. So when do these values get set and/or what can cause them to *not* be set?